# Converting can light to pendant fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I currently have 6 can lights in my kitchen. I would like to convert one of them to a pendant light. I know there are kits to do that but my question pertains to how to get the pendant light to go on and off separately from the remaining can lights? I would rather not tear out drywall to add a new line if possible. Also, the can lights are currently run by two different switches (at each end of the room, which may complicate matters. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is surface mounted wiring (surface raceway) an option? Are smart-switches an option, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the can lights are on you can install a pendant light that has an independant pull switch. However, this will only work if power is going to all lights currently wired together. If you have a junction box in the ceiling near the can light you are converting: You could bypass that particular can light in the circuit and run new wiring to the new pendant light that has a pull switch.

Answer (score 1):

To have control of this light separately from the others you would need to run a new wire. If the lights are turned off this light would not have power. You could install a smart switch in the fixture j box but this would only allow you to turn on / off when the other lights are on. So to have separate control some new wiring would be needed. Do you have attic access? If you have access above running a new circuit using a smart switch would eliminate the need for tearing out sheetrock. If you don't have access to provide independent functionality of the new light some sheetrock removal would be required.